# Creating a relationship between users

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a user form.  There are 4 types of users, but 2 of those types need to be connected using a many to many relationship.  Once connected, this relationship needs to be shown on the form and in a view.

So for example, currently the form contains the users name, desk number, mobile number, job title, department etc.  There is a view which shows these details too.

I now need the view and the form to show a connection between user types 1 and 2, where user 2 is a secretary and user 1 is not a secretary.  There can be many secretaries per type 1 user, and there can be 1 secretary for many type 1 users.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, is it?

Comment: Take a look at the Connections functionality in Dynamics - it should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Connection Roles functionality will do for you what exactly you want.